# Computing Cauchy Integrals in Sage Math

Tags: python, math, complex-numbers, sage, calculus

I am relatively new to complex analysis and I am trying to write down the following integral in Sage Math:

[image: Cauchy Integral Image Link]

If S(m,n), a formal power series, = (1-t^2)^m / (1-t)^n then the Cauchy integral is:

```
I(k) = 1/2ipi * int_o(S(m,n)t^(k+1) dt)
```

This is from a paper that can be found at:
http://magali.bardet.free.fr/Publis/ltx43BF.pdf
The contour is a circle around the origin with a radius less than 1.

The Cauchy Integral will produce the k-th coefficient of $S(n)$. I tried doing the following:

```py
def deg_reg_Cauchy(k, n, m):
    R.<t> = PowerSeriesRing(CC, 't')
    constant_term = 1/(2*I*pi)
    s = (1-t**2)**m / (t**(k+1)*(1-t)**n)
    s1 = constant_term * s.integral()
    return s1
```

I realize this is probably ***very*** wrong. Does anyone have any tips on how to go about this, please?

```py
ArithmeticError: The integral of is not a Laurent series since t^-1 has a nonzero coefficient.
```

Thank you!

Comment: Have you consider asking in  [AskSage](https://ask.sagemath.org/questions/) or [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/)?

Comment: I have, but no responses were given so I tried my luck here.

Comment: It’s saying that there’s a logarithmic term in the integral; you may need to treat it separately and remove that term from the input Laurent series.

Comment: Just as a point of context, this question might be okay on [math.stackexchange](math.stackexchange.com) but probably not MO.

Comment: [Link to the cross-post](https://ask.sagemath.org/question/47017/calculating-cauchy-integrals-in-sage/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably going to have to parametrize your integration domain (circle, here).  Or use a Cauchy residue type theorem, as [here](https://ask.sagemath.org/question/37395/trouble-with-an-integral/).

[Here is an interesting Sage cell instance by Jason Grout and Ben Woodruff](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJx1VE1v2zAMvQfIfyCSApFdN2vS0wr4EOw0YKd2wA5pGqg27Qi1JUOim-Tfj5LsrC26-BCafPx-9Hz--4BQmBLhBRtzhKNqGqiULoHY4HpbyQJBWpRgKpAXDR0kQaPQDX6VOGXnBCQ7yhfzhsG96C1LVlACSgfN6QxdIzUuAaaT6JN_vzk9r2_Oz-vpxENzsU4L41jK4C51SrOUTCdkpa4xF5TdZuu0U6yaTkqX22WpqooxS21sK1hdbvJKpD5UkpY-jkfO4RfSwkErX7kdqHpdkDIarKoPxK1VQAbwTTa9JAZoLpiwtrIBbsZy7crFdkLl8z-44Dn1zsfSfYtWFQwdfTIeSiG91ZkWSbU8piNCG3JpQ2zmKTXoc9ZIPh2eZEGXAEvuAiuer8b9qBODoMvkfjoB_lmk3mp4eBCXEr5AZxBHt13tLuJ6l2xvd2EwG8g_5Sk3weAO5igO1DaCfK1iO51s7ewqLu1qlkVhl0X10xsWYdNs8X-jvrwYvpXkbeO6BOXvUI5NYVcZvzDun7tTdSvzCiJk89H-OLBx4_l5lUNEQ_7Ezex_wOC18ehdkoS24sO054U6jCTwpHCBn11jKBL9Hf15G3bFxOuZm74THl0WWgoj7dORbRw_UGRvOh_W5aUqSBSmMTZfWCwXGdOoeNXoXH43gl3eSSuZJby_vU8vQq7bZFxWlqYfoibXXzqskuw_eL9KRPoiz-ghej6qVZIMS491XQeveDw_qzCPy03w7ErjWZF5vY7nET4dtRpu_0JlPpfO8hvM_Kcm8tzfGfo5f44qjlIRVMbyBl4UJfczf_nngfChugFOyEQdZ-RLx1OBHQ3IIeOjrP3XrW_KcHaFabuePtYXK2rOy9lfoD-cFg==&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==) that might help you get started on how to calculate some of them; unfortunately, sometimes these integrals are very tricky to do exactly.  See [this sage-support thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/sage-support/Ou4KVRv6wdk/KgJxR0eGHQYJ) for an easier example, though I don't think in the end it fully worked because of a Maxima bug.

Relevant code:

```
f(x,y)=9-x^2-y^2
r(t)=(2*cos(t), 3*sin(t))
trange=(t,0,2*pi)

ds=r.diff(t).norm()
dA=f(*r(t))*ds(t)

def line_integral(integrand):
    return RR(numerical_integral(integrand, trange[1], trange[2])[0])

A = line_integral(dA)
integrate(dA, trange)
```

The last two lines do a numerical and exact (if possible) result, respectively.